# Foundation 5 Accordion - Transition Speed?

Tags: javascript, html, css, zurb-foundation

I am using [Foundation 5 Accordions](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/accordion.html) on a Website. They work but I want to change the transition speed. Currently when you click they instantly hide one and show the other. I would prefer they transition vs instantly appearing.

I tried CSS but it didn't work:

```
.accordion dd > a{ 
   transition: all .5s;
}
```

Note: I am omitted vendor prefixes.

How do I get these to transition smoothly?

If I can do it with pure CSS this is preferred, otherwise JS will work but I am unsure how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out JS is the way to do this:

```
$(function() {
 $(".accordion").on("click", "dd:not(.active)", function (event) {
   $("dd.active").removeClass('active').find(".content").slideUp("fast");
   $(this).addClass('active').find(".content").slideToggle("fast");
 });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Lynda, I appreciated your code, in foundation 5, the panel stays visible after the second closing.  Seems to be caused by jQuery adding style attributes from sliding.  I edited it to fix the issue.

```
$(".accordion").on("click", "dd", function (event) {
        if($(this).hasClass('active')){
            $("dd.active").removeClass('active').find(".content").slideUp("fast");    
        }
        else {
            $("dd.active").removeClass('active').find(".content").slideUp("fast");
            $(this).addClass('active').find(".content").slideToggle("fast");    
        }
});
```

Comment: This one works fine with foundation 5 but I would like to extend it so we can expand more than one panel at a time. Right now it only expands one panel at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this structure:

```
$(function() {
  $(".accordion").on("click", "dd", function (event) {

   $("div.active").slideUp(100).removeClass('.active');
       $(this).find(".content").slideDown(100).addClass('active');

 })
});
```

Its work correctly.

Comment: you can try new structure, transition: all 1s ease;

Comment: Doesn't work. Also instead of using `div` (which I tried) I also tried `.accordion` and `dd`. Doesn't work. I did find a JS Solution but there is an issue with that. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that is a bit more in-depth with jQuery, as well as utilizing `.eq()` to specifically target only the first (position 0) `a` element clicked through all of the `li` elements. Theoretically, this should work if you add the `multi_expand` configuration as well, because it only targets the first `a` element.

```
$(".accordion li").on("click", "a:eq(0)", function (event) {
    var li_parent = $(this).parent();

        if (li_parent.hasClass('active')) {
            $(".accordion li div.content:visible").slideToggle("normal");
        } else {
            $(".accordion li div.content:visible").slideToggle("normal");
            $(this).parent().find(".content").slideToggle("normal");
        }
    });
```

Credit goes to Nemanja Andrejevic [on the Foundation forums.](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/743-accordions---how-do-you-animate-opening-and-closing-content) **Note:** this is using the Foundation 5.5 markup. If you're using previous versions, just replace all uses of `li` with `dd`.